# Viewing a form of WPF in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I wrote this method did not work

```
UserControl us = new UserControl();
us.Show();
```

Comment: I am just reading again the title of the question : do you want to mix WPF and Windows Forms technology ? If yes, is the UserControl  Windows Forms technology and the Windows a windows Form or is it the reverse ? If no, the title should be changed

Comment: Please could you answer about WPF/Windows Forms, so that the title of post could be updated if needed. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Your control has to be located in a window

```
Window  Window = new Window();
// window has a single content
// here it is usercontrol1
// to have many controls, use an intermediary like Grid or Canvas or any Panel derived class
window.Content = usercontrol1;
```

The Window has to be opened.

```
// modeless (non blocking) opening
window.Show();
```

or

```
// modal (blocking) opening
window.Showdialog();
```

Regards

Comment: Might be easier to change the UserControl to a Window (see my answer) than wrapping the UserControl two layers deep (WinForm > ElementHost > UserControl). Better access to its children too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't show a `UserControl`. Change your `UserControl` to a `Window`.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowsFormsApplication1.MyWindow"
```

instead of

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowsFormsApplication1.UserControl1"
```

and in your code-behind, change

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
```

to

```
public partial class MyWindow: Window
```

Now you can call `new MyWindow().Show();`. The major benefit is that you are not overburdening the application by adding a Windows Form dialog and an ElementHost and a UserControl inside it.

This way you can also access the children of the UserControl/Window from the calling Windows Form class.

Comment: But a UserControl IS NOT a window. Don't name a cat with a dog name ! I agree, you could forget Usercontrol and directly create a window

Comment: @EmmanuelDURIN Agreed - could lead to trouble later on. Lazy naming convention on my part. Updated the answer.